# Re-create a container from newer image

Tags: docker

So I have this service that I started in docker long ago with `--restart=always` and it's been around and working. The options it was started with were either never saved into a script, or the script is long lost, but docker dutifully restarts the service after every reboot, so everything works.

But now it's time to upgrade the service. How to re-create the container with new image so that it gets the same environment variables, volumes, bind mounts and all the other options defined on docker command-line back when it was created (and preferably also the same IP address)?

Comment: The [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) command may be a solution, but without the IP address I would think.

Comment: @berndbausch no, it isn't. commit saves the state of a container, but not the parameters, as a new image, while I want to discard the state, pull a new container and run it with the same parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### For the future

Switch to [`podman`](https://podman.io/), make the containers persistent the correct Linux way using [`podman generate systemd`](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-generate-systemd.1.html) and they will be trivially updatable with [`podman auto-update`](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-auto-update.1.html). Some labels need to be applied as per description of `podman auto-update`.

### For existing containers

- Fish out the arguments from `docker inspect`. The arguments and entry point are mixed up with the defaults there, so inspecting the image may be needed too if it is not obvious which parameters are non-default.
- Copy out the content of any volumes (if using volumes rather than bind-mounts)
- Create the containers with [`podman`](https://podman.io/), make it persistent with [`podman generate systemd`](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-generate-systemd.1.html) and then it is ready for future updates.
- Uninstall docker with extreme prejudice.